# Are cdecl and system-V-i386-ABI similar?

Tags: c, calling-convention

I compiled the same C source twice:

1. Arch: x86, O.S.: Slackware 14 (32bit), compiler: gcc 4.7.1 (32 bit)
2. Arch: x86, O.S.: Windows XP (32bit), compiler: gcc 4.4.1 (32bit)

Reading the assembler listing I noticed that calling conventions (System V i386 ABI and cdecl) seem identical, except for name decorations (missing trailing _ in the first case) and callee-saved registers (EDI, ESI, EBX vs EAX, ECX, EDX).

Is it really true?
If so, except for name decorations, may we consider System V i386 ABI as a   variant of cdecl?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about those registers? That doesn't look right. The compilers might have allocated registers differently because of changes between 4.4 and 4.7 so a side-by-side listing won't match up directly. As far as I know, "cdecl" is just Microsoft's name for "the SysV ABI for function calling"

Comment: Thank you; I was wrong: in cdecl EAX, ECX, EDX are caller-saved, not callee-saved.